# user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong or error: insufficient permissions for device: udev requires plugdev group membership?

Tags: android, udev, adb

I encountered error like "(user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?", After googled, I found some key refers:

- Ref 1. [Set up a device for development from Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up);
- Ref 2. [Solved: no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?): Solution 3](https://www.lynxbee.com/solved-no-permissions-user-in-plugdev-group-are-your-udev-rules-wrong/);
- Ref 3. [Android udev rules list aimed to be the most comprehensive on the net](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules);

It seems I should have fixed my error since I found **Ref 2** as above; As [Android Developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up) say:

> **Ubuntu Linux**: Use `apt-get install` to install the `adb` package. This gives you a community-maintained default set of `udev` rules for all Android devices.

I was confused because I had env variable `ANDROID_HOME`on 16.04LTS(my current use) and export two below which I **DO NOT** install `adb` with `apt-get install adb`.

```
# set android adb tools
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I checked `/etc/udev/rules.d/` which have `170-snap.core.rules  70-snap.vlc.rules`. Was that(not install `apt-get install adb`) I missed this file `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`? Answer is **NO**.

1. Which adb package I should use on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, "~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb" or "sudo apt-get adb"?

   > As **danzel**(nice and humorous person below) and Andoroid developer [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up) suggest, I keep two export as mentioned above and `sudo apt-get install adb` for a community-maintained default set of udev rules for all Android devices.
2. Should I add this `51-android.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` meanwhile I backup thoes two `70-snap.core.rules  70-snap.vlc.rules`?

   > 1. They have no relationship.
   > 2. As [Android developer docs(webpage language as Chinese or '中文-简体')](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#setting-up) say, developers create `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file as root or `sudo` command, use `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` change privilege of this file. 
   >      Add rule into this file, check [Solution 3](https://www.lynxbee.com/solved-no-permissions-user-in-plugdev-group-are-your-udev-rules-wrong/).
   > 3. Other files are **NOT** mentioned, so don't touch them.
3. Will be caused unreversed errors for my developer computer env?

   > I laughed myself just as danzel(nice and humorous person below) said `"the inverse operation of creating a file is deleting it"`;

Latest updated: **2019-09-02**

Comment: You can use whichever adb you want. The suggestion to install adb via apt is for the sole purpose of obtaining the community maintained udev rules (and updates thereof). The udev rules you mentioned are not related to adb, just leave them as they are. Does this answer your questions? I honestly don't really understand your actual problem.

Comment: Part of the question. Try to solve "user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?" error. Should I copy  `51-android.rules` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory and make a rule into it, or make a rule into one of those `70-snap.core.rules  70-snap.vlc.rules`. Thx!

Comment: Yes, `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is the correct directory. As I said, don't touch the existing (unrelated) rules files. They could be overwritten by the packages that provided them in the future. Additionally, the number at the beginning of the filename (or, more precicely, the whole filename) determines the order in which the rules are applied. There is probably a reason  for the `51` and the rules may not work if they are applied later. As for your third question (sorry for the sarcasm): the inverse operation of creating a file is deleting it.

Comment: However, if you don't mind having an additional adb installation (which you don't have to use), you can just install adb via apt (`sudo apt install adb`) which will install (and update) the appropriate udev rules so you don't have to add them manually.

Comment: @danzel Thx a lot, I really appreciate it. I will update this question and post the right answer later. Maybe polish my not proper question.

Comment: @Shanksiscool Could you post the answer if you have it?

Comment: @user.dz Developers create `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file as root or sudo command, use `chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` change privilege of this file. Add rule into this file, check [Solution 3](https://www.lynxbee.com/solved-no-permissions-user-in-plugdev-group-are-your-udev-rules-wrong/) know how to make a rule.

Comment: @Shanksiscool could you please post that as an "answer", not "comment" , Ask Ubuntu is Q/A site. See https://askubuntu.com/tour . It will be easier  to search for solution. Let me know when you do, so I give an up vote :).

Answer (score 4):

There are some specific things to do for Ubuntu to make USB debugging work, described in [this page on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device) about setting up a device for development.

What it suggests is to run these two commands in terminal:

```
sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME
sudo apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common
```

The above package contains a community-maintained set of udev rules for Android devices.

Rebooting may be needed for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**: you need create `sudo /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file as **root** privilege, then use `sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` change privilege of this file. Add rule into this file, check [Solution 3](https://www.lynxbee.com/solved-no-permissions-user-in-plugdev-group-are-your-udev-rules-wrong/) know how to make a rule.

Comment: what does the number 51 mean? Sometimes I see 50, 51, or 70....

Comment: since it is out of my ability. Just googled the key might be `Files in /etc/udev/rules.d/ are parsed in lexical order, and in some circumstances, the order in which rules are parsed is important.` and `Files in the custom rules directory override files of the same name in the default rules directory. Rules files are sorted and processed in lexical order.`, or you may find out by you own with help of [link 1](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#syntax) and [link 2](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/beginners-guide-to-udev-in-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Have your android asked if it can trust this computer? my fix was that, please check on the phone side first by plugging it and looking if is asking for permission